# windows authentication for multiple user in same domain

Tags: c#, html, .net

I want all the users from same domain name: XYZ to access my application below is my code.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows"  />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="XYZ\HOW TO GRANT ACCESS TO ALL THE USERS HERE?" />
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Domain Users

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="XYZ\Domain Users"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working I have another question. If users are from different domain I want Login.aspx to open. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I am sorry its not working. After I changed the domain and ran the webpage opened. So its not working :(

Comment: To redirect users to Login.aspx you would need to use the `authentication` tag. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET) is a nice little tutorial about both

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and also disable Anonymous Authentication and only enable Integrated Windows Auth.

```
`<authentication mode="Windows" />
   <authorization>
   <allow roles="XYZ\Domain Users" />
   <deny users="*" />
 </authorization>`
```